# How to convert long long to 8 byte array in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application i have to convert long long number into 8 byte array. Then i have to convert 8 byte array into hexadecimel string. Can you please help me in this. i'm struck up.

Comment: so long long to hexadecimal string?

Comment: See [how to get the Nth byte of an integer][1], and modify as necessary.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787423/c-get-nth-byte-of-integer

Comment: Try this format: `NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08llx", llVal];` where llVal is you long long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do integer/byte array conversion is to use a `union`:

```
union {
    long long l;
    uint8_t b[sizeof(long long)];
} u;

u.l = mylonglong;
```

Then `u.b[]` contains the bytes, which can be accessed individually.

**EDIT**: Please note as pointed out by @NikolaiRuhe this use of `union` can lead to undefined behaviour, so it might be best to use `memcpy()` instead:

```
uint8_t b[sizeof(long long)];
memcpy(b, &mylonglong, sizeof(b));
```

If you want the hex string of the `long long` in native-endian order, then:

```
void hexChar(uint8_t b, char *out)
{
    static const char *chars = "0123456789abcdef";
    out[0] = chars[(b >> 4) & 0xf];
    out[1] = chars[b & 0xf];
}

// Make sure outbuf is big enough
void hexChars(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t len, char *outbuf)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        hexChar(buffer[i], outbuf);
        outbuf += 2;
    }
    *outbuf = '\0';
}
```

and call it with:

```
char hex[32];
hexChars(u.b, sizeof(u.b), hex);
```

However if instead you want the hex value of the `long long`:

```
char hex[32];
sprintf(hex, "%llx", mylonglong);
```

Comment: I'm new to this. Can you please correct me if i'm doing it wrong way.
 union {
        long long l;
        uint8_t b[sizeof(long long)];
    } u;
    
    u.l = longvalue;
    dataWithBytes=[NSData dataWithBytes:u.b length:sizeof(u.b)];
Then i'm converting NSData into Hex string. But i'm getting wrong result.

Comment: @PremPalanisamy Yeah that looks OK to me.

Comment: @PremPalanisamy How are you converting the `NSData` object into a hex string?  Have you considered endian issues (i.e. iOS and OSX use little endian where the byte order is reversed)?

Comment: Using a union to write one element and then read another relies on undefined behavior. It probably works on most platforms, yet the C standard explicitly warns about this.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe That surprises me.  Can you provide a link please?

Comment: I dont have a link to the standard (I'm on a phone) but google has lots of hits for "C union undefined behavior". Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2310534/104790

Comment: Generally in C, when converting data types bitwise it's necessary to use `memcpy`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe OK thanks.  I will need to caveat that use of `union` then to make it obvious it can lead to undefined behaviour and I will suggest `memcpy()` instead.

Comment: char hex[32];
sprintf(hex, "%llx", mylonglong);

This will do the trick. Thanks for the quick response. Anyway have to cross check with server decryption also.

Answer (score 0):

would that do the trick ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    long long int val = 0x424242;
    char str_val[32];
    snprintf(str_val, sizeof(str_val), "%#llx", val);
    printf("Value : %s\n", str_val);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that you just need to put it in a string. If you really need to get your 8 byte array, see trojanfoe's solution.