# how to get last 4 bytes of a timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
console.og(Date.now() & 0xffffffff)
```

I got `-1798272874` which is not what I want, I want a positive integer not a negative number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you zero-fill right shift (`>>>`) by 0 bits, JavaScript will give you an unsigned representation of the number.  So your code from above would become,

```
console.log((Date.now() & 0xffffffff) >>> 0)
```

which will result in something like `2497628378`.

See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it) and [the MDN documentation for zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E%3E_%28Zero-fill_right_shift%29) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.

```
var date = Date.now();
var bytes = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    bytes[i] = (date >> (8*i)) & 0xff;
}
console.log(bytes);
```

Got the operation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787423/c-get-nth-byte-of-integer)