# Get single bytes from a word

Tags: c, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the value of individual bytes of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680220/how-to-get-the-value-of-individual-bytes-of-a-variable)

How can I get single bytes from a word (for example an *unsigned int* in C) without using bit-wise operations (that is using arithmetic operations?)

I don't know why, but this formula (C-Like) for an *x* number doesn't seem to work:

```
floor(x / pow(R, i)) % R
```

where `R` is the radix with which the number is represented, and `i` is used to indicate the `i`-th byte to obtain.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use bitwise operators?

Comment: This is your 6th question. You have accepted no answers and never voted. Please read the [faq] and make an effort to give back to the community from which you ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to avoid bitwise operations, you can cheat alternatively (beware if you're using a little or big endian machine!):

```
char *int_16_storage;
uint16_t the_word = 0xabcd;
int_16_storage = &the_word;

uint8_t low_byte = int_16_storage[0];
uint8_t high_byte = int_16_storage[1];
```

Comment: Could also be done using a union, which doesn't rely on pointers to work.

Comment: What's the problem with pointers?

Comment: Nothing is 'wrong' with pointers, but they can make code harder to read. With a union, it is much easier to determine what you are accomplishing.

Comment: On the other hand, such use of unions is undefined and distinctly non-portable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "non-portable", yes. "Undefined", not in C90 and not in C99TC3 as clarified by footnote 82.