# C integer to binary conversion, splitting the result into two binary values

Tags: c, variables, binary, type-conversion, integer

I have a integer value e.g. : `int data_value = 1150;`
I want to split this into two binary variables like this: value is binary_data_value `0X04,0X7E`
It just needs to be 2 binary values which, are 8 bits long each.

How is it best to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: `data_value & 0xFF` and `(data_value >> 8) & 0xFF`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted thank you. Fyi this is what i did with it: `int t1_value_1 = (T1_value >>8) & 0XFF;//MSB shifting
    int t1_value_2 = T1_value & 0XFF;//LSB

    int t2_value_1 = (T2_value >> 8) & 0XFF;//MSB
    int t2_value_2 = T2_value & 0XFF;//LSB
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of individual bytes of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680220/how-to-get-the-value-of-individual-bytes-of-a-variable)

Comment: Just make sure to never use bit shifts on signed types. `int` is signed.