# Get single byte from int

Tags: c#, binary

I got an int number. For example 5630(decimal). The number in binary is:

> 00000000 00000000 00010101 11111110

I want to get the second byte in decimal (00010101).
How do I get it?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`BitConverter.GetBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx):

```
int intValue = 5630;
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
byte result = intBytes[1];  // second least-significant byte
```

or just bit-shift 8 places to the right and convert to a byte (truncating the left bits):

```
((byte)(intValue >> 8))
```

Comment: Only the second approach (shifting) would be recommended IMO. The first is inefficient, and endianness-dependent.

Answer (score 3):

do a bitwise And with `00000000 00000000 11111111 00000000`
(in hex, `0xFF00`), and right shift by 8 places.

```
  var x = 5630;
  var secondByte = (x & 0xFF00) >> 8;
```

or, bit-shift first and strip off higher order bytes by &-ing with value
`00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`
decimal 255, or  (hex `0xFF`)

```
  var x = 5630;
  var secondByte = (x >> 8) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: I like this answer because it's the most CS-y.

Comment: Huh??  What is CS-y ??

Comment: Oh, the CS is for C-Sharp?  is this a sarcastic criticism?  If so it is ignorant. The only consequence to someone who does not understand it is that it provides an opportunity for them to learn something.  This is true for all of us, in every field of knowledge or endeavor.

Comment: @Charles "Computer science". Also: don't be so defensive - this *is the right answer*.

Comment: @Trevor I don't think that's a fair or reasonable interpretation. In other news: if your team don't know what bits are (and how to work with them) - time to *get a better team*... Just sayin'

Comment: @Marc,  you are right.  sorry... I am  probably hyper-sensitive on this general topic.. I remember taking too much heat from using ternary operator, and then the double ?? operator back in the days before their use spread through the community. The arguments on those issues, back then, were similar...  I am very much an "early adopter", and I enjoy learning and using, new language features,  but many are not.

Comment: "using ternary operator"... You meant the "conditional" operator, right? (Grinning here; this is tongue in cheek; honestly, I would pay the c# team in beer and steak for a week if they added another ternary operator, just for fun)

Comment: @Marc, <grin />  ternary is considered synonym for conditional operator.. .   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:  but you are technically correct.  it really is just term for any operator with three arguments...

Comment: @David, Thanks, yes,  one byte requires 2Fs in hex... stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Bitshift down and cast to `byte`

```
int num = 5630;
byte second_byte = (byte)(num >> 8);
```