# C# syntax for delphi 7 statement

Tags: c#, delphi

I have below third party code in Delphi 7 which I need to convert to C#, Neither I am getting this syntax of declaration in C#, not the usage of it in the code. This is quite strange that I tried converting the code form some online Compilers, but the compiler did not converted all the line, specially the declaration part.

```
 type
      balongint = array[0..3] of byte;
.
.
.
case balongint(b)[x] of
```

can someone help me out for the same. What is this syntax in Delphi-7? 
in this statement case balongint(b)[x] of 'b' and 'x' are of type Integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Delphi code `b` is a type of size 4 bytes, `Integer`.  The cast to `balongint` interprets that 4 byte value as an array of byte. The indexing `[x]` picks out the byte with index `x`.

In C# you use `BitConverter.GetBytes` as seen in this question: [Get single byte from int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821262/get-single-byte-from-int)

Comment: Hey  @David Heffernan !!
Need more help!! for below syntax-
lp :^longint;
stt:string;
wp = ^word;
.
.
.
        stt := '#$F9';
        lip(@stt[2])^ := adj;
        wp(@stt[6])^ := nts;
        wp(@stt[8])^ := word(z);
Do I need to post another question?

Comment: Do you know any Pascal at all?

Comment: You can't just add new questions in an edit. One at time please. You'd have to ask a new question. I reverted your edit. Again, do you know Pascal at all?

Comment: I am working on migration of a code of Delphi 7 to C#. I worked in Delphi-7, but I never worked on Pointers (I know basics of Pointers) in Delphi, Therefore it was quite confusing to me to convert the same in C#.

Comment: Well I tried a bit and found implement a solution with below code-
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(someIntNumber);
string byteArray = BitConverter.ToString(b).Replace("-", "");