# Get nth byte of integer

Tags: python, byte

I have the following integer:

```
target = 0xd386d209
print hex(target)
```

How can I print the nth byte of this integer? For example, expected output for the first byte would be:

```
0x09
```

Comment: How would you do it by hand?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks that was the tip I needed... `print hex(0x000000FF & target)`

Comment: it may be preferable to print `'{:02x}'.format( (target >> (8*n)) & 0xff )` (instead of using `hex`) such that you get a leading zero (like `09`) when the leading nibble is zero.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with the help of bit manipulation. Create a bit mask for an entire byte, then bitshift that mask the number of bytes you'd like. Mask out the byte using binary AND and finally bitshift back the result to the first position:

```
target = 0xd386d209
byte_index = 0
mask = 0xFF << (8 * byte_index)
print hex((target & mask) >> (8 * byte_index))
```

You can simplify it a little bit by shifting the input number first. Then you don't need to bitshift the `mask` value at all:

```
target = 0xd386d209
byte_index = 0
mask = 0xFF
print hex((target >> (8 * byte_index)) & mask)
```

Comment: I think the variable _bit_index_ should be renamed to _byte_index_ or something to make it clearer as we're denoting the _nth_ byte with this variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
def byte(number, i):
    return (number & (0xff << (i * 8))) >> (i * 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def print_n_byte(target, n):
...     return hex((target&(0xFF<<(8*n)))>>(8*n))
... 
>>> print_n_byte(0xd386d209, 0)
'0x9L'
>>> print_n_byte(0xd386d209, 1)
'0xd2L'
>>> print_n_byte(0xd386d209, 2)
'0x86L'
```

Answer (score 0):

This only involves some simple binary operation.

```
>>> target = 0xd386d209
>>> b = 1
>>> hex((target & (0xff << b * 8)) >> b * 8)
'0x9'
>>> hex((target & (0xff << b * 8)) >> b * 8)
'0xd2'
```